# How can I validate text boxes to prevent passing empty values?

Tags: jquery

I have two input fields that shows below and I would like to output an alert when clicked the button if there are any empty field.

HTML:

```
<input placeholder="Day" id="day" type="number" name="day">      
<input placeholder="Year" id="year" type="number" name="year">
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
   $('button').click(function(){

     day = $("#day").val();
     month = $("select option:selected").val()
     year = $("#year").val(); 
     pdate = currentYear - year ;

     if( day === "" && year === ""  ){

        alert("the fields are empty");
     }
     else{
       alert("Congratulations");
     }
   });    
});
```

At the moment, when I click on a button,the else statement works even if one of the fields is empty.

Comment: use or operator `if( day.trim() === "" || year.trim() === ""  ){`

Comment: @Nadj see my updated answer updated year & date validation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declare the variables with `var` and replace with `&&(and)both condition are satisfied` to `||(or)Either one condition satisfied`

better use `!` its will check all condition is`null,empty`

***year validation updated***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
       $('button').click(function(){
            
        var day = $("#day").val();
         var month = $("select option:selected").val()
         var year = $("#year").val(); 
         var pdate = currentYear - year ;
         
         if((!day )||(!year)){
          
            alert("the fields are empty");
         }
           //updated
         else if((day < 0)|| (year <1920))
         
         {alert('not allow date below 0 & year below 1920');}
         else{
           alert("Congratulations");
         }
         });    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Day" id="day" type="number" name="day">      
    <input placeholder="Year" id="year" type="number" name="year">
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: @prasad.Thanks it does what I asked. Mind updating the snippet to validate the year input no never accept number below 1920 and the day to never accept number below 0?
Hope you can help there

Comment: @Nadj see my updated answer updated year & date validation as per your need ..hope this help..!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the values using an OR (`||`) operator rather than an AND (`&&`); as it stands you're checking to see if *both* values are empty-strings (which will fail if only *one* of the strings is empty), whereas it seems you want to check if *either* value is an empty string, which would be:

```
if ( day === "" || year === ""  )
```

It is, however, worth pointing out that your checks would fail to catch a string of multiple white-spaces, so you may want to re-write the conditions to first trim white-space from the value:

```
if (day.trim() === "" || year.trim() === "")
```

`String.prototype.trim()` removes the leading and trailing white-space from a String.

Incidentally, your variable declarations seem to be missing, so unless you declared them elsewhere in the scope of this posted snippet they will be global variables which is, usually, an unwanted problem (and prone to being changed accidentally elsewhere in the code); to fix this you should declare them using either `var` or `let` (or `const`, but I'm unsure whether you need them to be constant or not) to localise them to the local scope.

References:

- [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).
- [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).
- [Logical AND (`&&`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND).
- [Logical OR (`||`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Comment: ThomasDid you test your answer?cause I did that and it didn't really work.

Comment: What does "*it didn't really work*" mean, in context? What didn't it do, what does it do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. Use jquery trim method to escape spaces(if user input only spaces).

```
var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
$(document).on('click','button',function(){

 day = $("#day").val();
 month = $("select option:selected").val()
 year = $("#year").val(); 
 pdate = currentYear - year ;

 if( $.trim(day) != "" && $.trim(year) != ""){
     alert("Congratulations");
 }
 else{
   alert("the fields are empty");
 }
});
```